# How do I make .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 install quietly?

Tags: installation, windows-8.1, 64-bit, .net-framework, installer

I am trying to install, as part of my chained bootstrapper installation project, .NET Framework 3.5 SP1. But, when you run the installer, even by itself, with `/q /norestart`, it is anything but quiet. I would expect no user interface, yet I get presented with the following:

[image]

Is there any way to actually make it quiet? I've looked at other threads on Stack and elsewhere, and they all seem to imply that this would be the way to make the installation take place quietly, yet it doesn't.

**Note**: I know, in the command prompt screenshot I used `\`, but even with `/`, same thing.

**Note**: I've tried both the full and not-full versions of the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 redistributable; same thing.

Comment: Are you sure your `dotnetfx35setup.exe` is the .NET installer?

Comment: @Jublo Yup. Either this http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=22 or this http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=25150

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.Net 3.5 is already part of Windows 8, so the installer doesn't work. You can use [DISM to install .Net 3.5](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn482069.aspx):

```
DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /All /LimitAccess /Source:d:\sources\sxs
```

Comment: *DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /All* worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: I think it also automatically installs the latest SP level for that framework version as well, with the above command I linked. Just checked the registry for the SP value under *HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5* and it is set to 1.

Comment: *DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /All* downloads the files from the Internet which may not work all the time. And since Windows 7 the .Net 3.5 is at Sp1 level.

Comment: Yeah, but its better than */Source:d:\sources\sxs*...getting the sources and making them available isn't exactly a walk in the park.

Answer (score -1):

Try calling the installer with these parameters:

```
dotnetfx35setup.exe /qb /norestart
```

Also, make sure all setup packages are not missing, you can use [.NET Framework 3.5 SP1 full install package](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/0/e/20e90413-712f-438c-988e-fdaa79a8ac3d/dotnetfx35.exe).

Comment: Have you actually had success with this? What OS version are you using? /qb won't work for me. I'm on Windows 8.1 x64.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test, since I'm running Windows 8.1 and have .NET 4.0 installed.

Comment: Neither `/q` or `/qb` work for me. I still get the dialog as per the OP.

Answer (score -1):

The `/q` option is the correct one (`/q`, not `\q`):

```
dotnetfx35.exe /lang:ENU /q
```

This syntax is used in `winetricks` and it installs *.NET* correctly (see: [`load_dotnet35sp1()`](https://github.com/Winetricks/winetricks/blob/413f667e1fe6e6bc4a88f636b5f0103aab2f99b9/src/winetricks#L6906)).

If it doesn't, make sure you've the right version of the [`dotnetfx35.exe` file](https://download.microsoft.com/download/2/0/e/20e90413-712f-438c-988e-fdaa79a8ac3d/dotnetfx35.exe).

---

#### [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)

Alternatively you can use [*AutoHotKey*](https://www.autohotkey.com/) to automate any installer wizzard.

Here is the example taken from `winetricks`:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
run, dotnetfx35.exe /lang:ENU /q

Loop
{
    sleep 1000
    ifwinexist,, cannot be uninstalled
    {
        WinClose,, cannot be uninstalled
        continue
    }
    Process, exist, dotnetfx35.exe
    dotnet_pid = %ErrorLevel%
    if dotnet_pid = 0
    {
        break
    }
 }
```

Comment: this installer doesn't work for Windows 8.x or Windows 10. look for the used windows tags in the question, first.